# Symbol not found in flat namespace '_MQBACK' (Python3.9 - MacOS 12.1 Silicon)

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, pymqi

Installing `pymqi` in a MacOS M1 Pro 12.1 Monterey, Python 3.9.9 in a virtualenv and the usual suspect appeared again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a.gounaris/.virtualenvs/mxhub39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 132, in <module>
    from . import pymqe # type: ignore
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/a.gounaris/.virtualenvs/mxhub39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymqi/pymqe.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_MQBACK'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/a.gounaris/.virtualenvs/mxhub39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymqi/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import pymqe # type: ignore # Backward compatibility
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymqe'
```

All paths are in place `/opt/mqm/bin:/opt/mqm/samp/bin` and Python sees the env variable `os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH']=='/opt/mqm/lib64'`

After reinstalling pymqi with --verbose flag, this warning showed up:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqic_r.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
```

Might be the root cause of the exception symbol not found in flat namespace '_MQBACK' in M1 Pro Silicon platforms ?
It says that `ibmqic_r.dylib` is ignored.

Would a new release of MacOS Toolkit build for macOS-arm64 solve the issue?

Another option - theoretically speaking - could be to run the build for macOS-x86_64 with Rosetta 2 as suggested in this post, I don't know how to do it..

Any help will be mostly appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling the MacOS toolkit for IBM MQ is an x64 - or have you found one for arm?

Comment: @MoragHughson That is my suspicion too, have to wait for a new release soon, I hope.